# how to handle error 404 when img is not avilable in assest folder of that url in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic4

img tag throwing an error 404 when img is not available instead of throwing an error I want one avtar image with the first char of user name should come. suppose user name Ravi than R should come instead of error

I have tried with the boolean flag but it doesn't work for me for getting first char i have tried in alt attribute list.name.charAt(0)
but still, img error is coming

```
         <ion-item lines="none">
            <ion-thumbnail slot="start" rounded >
              <ion-img [src]="'assets/icon/' +list?.type+ '.png'" >                
             </ion-img>
            </ion-thumbnail>
            <ion-text slot="end"></ion-text>
            <ion-button  (click)="doAdd(list.type ,'')" slot="end">
                Add link
              </ion-button>
          </ion-item>
```

output should when img is not available then user first char of name should come instead of error

Answer (score 5):

Images have the `onerror` property, for ionic it is `ionError` (see [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/img)), you can use to execute code.

```
<img [src]="'assets/icons/'+list?.type+'.png'" (ionError)="handleError(i)">
```

There you can set an alternative `src` attribute for your image instead.

```
export class MyPage {
  list: YourListType[];

  handleError(index: number) {
    this.list[index].type = 'alternative-image-name';
    // note that in your template you concat that with the `assets/icon` path and the .png ending
  }
}
```

Comment: actually the list is an array of object with name listings and on error handler i want to show first char of type not any img

Comment: Then retrieve the index of the item which fails by `*ngFor="let item of list; let i = index"` and pass it to the `handleError` function. There you can overwrite the url of the item in your list.

Comment: on handleerror method, I want type first char instead of image can you help me out

Comment: I don't know what you mean

Comment: like if on Gmail if you haven't provided img that it will show first char of your name on image

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this.i hope your error will solve

```js
imageUrl(list){
  if(list.type){
  return "assets/icon/" + list?.type + ".png"
  } else {
  return "assets/icon/avatar.png"
  }
}
```

```html
         <ion-item lines="none">
            <ion-thumbnail slot="start" rounded >
              <ion-img [src]="imageUrl(list)" >                
             </ion-img>
            </ion-thumbnail>
            <ion-text slot="end"></ion-text>
            <ion-button  (click)="doAdd(list.type ,'')" slot="end">
                Add link
              </ion-button>
          </ion-item>
```

Comment: no this will not work because i have tried this thank for giving answer