# Error events for failed load images in ionic tags

Tags: angular, error-handling, event-handling, ionic4, angular7

I have this ion-img tag

```html
<ion-avatar [ngClass]="cssClass">
  <ion-img
  [src]="avatar"
  (ionError)="failedImageLoad($event)"></ion-img>
</ion-avatar>
```

And i need to send an error event when the image failed to load, this `(ionError)` event is in the documentation of the ion-img tag, but it doenst work, and the other events handler are working fine, someone knows any other event handler for error ?

Comment: Which version you are using? May be ionError added from ionic 4.2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to handle error 404 when img is not avilable in assest folder of that url in angular 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57392942/how-to-handle-error-404-when-img-is-not-avilable-in-assest-folder-of-that-url-in)

Answer (score 2):

**My solution for image load error**

```
<img class="avatar" [src]="merchant.logo_url" (error)="errorImage(img)" #img />



  errorImage(img) {
    
    img.src = '../../../../../../assets/svg-icons/022-menu.svg'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have something else going on as it's working for me:

```
<ion-img src="notfound.png" (ionError)="onError()"></ion-img>
```

With this handler in the codebehind:

```
  onError() {
    console.log("IMG ERROR");
  }
```

And this output:

[image]

Are you sure you have got the correct name for your error handler function?

`failedImageLoad()`

## update

Based on your comment you are dealing with a 403 error.

I [looked at the code](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/img/img.tsx#L101) and the `ionError` is really just a wrapper for the html img `onerror` event.

This is [defined on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Image_loading_errors):

- The src attribute is empty or null.
- The specified src URL is the same as the URL of the page the user is currently on.
- The specified image is corrupted in some way that prevents it from being loaded.
- The specified image's metadata is corrupted in such a way that it's impossible to retrieve its dimensions, and no dimensions were specified in the  element's attributes.
- The specified image is in a format not supported by the user agent.

So it seems that it should trigger the error.

Just to be sure: you mention two separate files this time, which wasn't in your original question. Have you put the image handler in both of them?

Comment: The name of the function is the same in both files, but what im binding in the ion-img tag is a link that throws an ``403 forbidden`` error in console when the image doenst exist in the server, maybe the ionError function doenst see this as an error ?

Answer (score 0):

## Simple solution.

### ionError : solution

```
fallbackUrl = 'assets/img/fallback-image.png';
<ion-img  [src]="user.userMg" (ionError)="user.userMg = fallbackUrl"></ion-img>
```

Comment: What do you call sweet?